# HAProxy Forwarding request rules

Tags: haproxy

I have a requirement where:

```
Incoming request- <haproxyIP>:8080/proxy/component/upgrade
Forward to- <serverIP>:8443/component/upgrade

Incoming request- haproxyIP:8080/proxy/component/restore
Forward to- <serverIP>:8443/component/restore
```

I've currently written my frontend and backend as:

```
frontend http-in
    acl acl_upgrade path_sub /proxy/component/upgrade
    use_backend b_upgrade if acl_upgrade
    acl acl_restore path_sub /proxy/component/restore
    use_backend b_restore if acl_restore

backend b_upgrade
    mode http
    http-request set-path /component/upgrade
    server s1 10.1.1.1:8443 ssl verify none

backend b_restore
    mode http
    http-request set-path /component/upgrade
    server s2 10.1.1.1:8443 ssl verify none
```

Instead of writing two backends, is it possible to have just one backend using something like regex, based on the part of the URL such as:

```
Incoming request- <haproxyIP>:8080/proxy/<extracted part>
Forward to- <serverIP>:8443/<extracted part>
```

Is it possible to do something like this in haproxy?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a map.
Example below is untested but it shows the idea.

url4setpath.cfg

```
# map url4setpath
/proxy/component/upgrade /component/upgrade
/proxy/component/restore /component/restore
```

```
frontend http-in

    use_backend b_default

backend b_upgrade
    mode http
    http-request set-path path,map_beg(url4setpath.cfg,/)
    server s1 10.1.1.1:8443 ssl verify none
```

More about maps [Introduction to HAProxy Maps](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-maps/)